# Markov inequality on tossing a fair die n times

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

I am tossing a fair die $n$ times. What is the the probability that the sum of the numbers is at most $2n$.
I am doing this in the following way:
I found $\mathbb E[X] = 3.5n$
So 
$$\Pr[X\leq 2n] = 1 - P[X > 2n]$$
According to Markov inequality:
$$P[X>2n] \leq E[X]/2n = 3.5n/2n = 3.5/2 =1.75$$
So $P[X \leq 2n] > 1 - 1.75 = -0.75$.
I am not sure where I am going wrong? How a probability can be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that in order for $n$ rolls to sum to no more than $2n$, each die roll can only be $1$ or $2$. Thus

$$P[X\le 2n]=(1/3)^n.$$

No Markov inequality required!

There is nothing wrong with your inequality by the way. Using the Markov inequality, you simply noted that the probability is bounded below by $-0.75$, which is true, technically!

EDIT: It has been observed that my initial attempt at this was flawed. While restricting the die rolls to all $1$'s and $2$'s is sufficient, it is not necessary, so the most we can say is that 
$$P[X\le 2n]\ge (1/3)^n.$$
I am trying to compute this completely and will update again soon.

Comment: Your statement is false ! If you get 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 for instance, that's a score of 11 over 6 rolls, you do have a 6, and 11 < 2*6 !

Comment: Good point. I can't believe I over looked that!

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with using Markov's inequality here. It is only that (since the calculated upper bound is greater than one) the inequality does not forbid $P[X\le 2n]$ from taking certain values *per se*, and is thus ineffective in this situation.

Comment: so how should we tackle with this problem

Comment: @bunny Essentially this is a combinatorial problem and the best answer involves generating functions. I'll leave it to you too look them up on MSE.